# .gitignore arbitrary sub git repositories

Tags: git, glob, gitignore

I'm trying to find a catch-all solution for a `.gitignore` to exclude any directories containing another git repository. The motivation is to be able to locally organize git-repositories hierarchically without `git status` telling you there is something untracked.

In my mind it would look like;

```
# exclude sub git directories
**/.git/..
```

and as I understand the disassembled parts

- `**` : anywhere in the repository
- `/` : any directory
- `.git/` : with a `.git/` directory
- `..` : exclude the directory containing the `.git/`

An example would be to exclude `bar/`-directory in the `foo/`-repository from file-tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXgjR.png

However, git does not seem to regard `foo/bar/.git/..` equivalent to `foo/bar/`, or `foo/bar/./` for that matter.

Suggestions?

Comment: Git will never store a Git repository into a Git repository. Any sub-*directory* that contains a `.git` will be treated as a sub*module*. You can't climb back up with `..` though; you just have to list all the submodules you'd like ignored, or avoid adding them (a regular `git add .` won't add half-assed submodules, if I remember right, but that's worth checking).